# Probability of receiving $k$ numbers out of $n$ in increasing or decreasing order

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you receive a sequence of $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$ numbers chosen independently and at random from a uniform distribution over the first $n$ natural numbers. What is the probability that, within this sequence, you have a monotonically increasing or decreasing sequence (not a sub-sequence; Erdos-Szekeres doesn't apply) of length $k$?

Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if it should be $\frac{2}{k!}(n-k+1) * \frac{(n-k)!}{n^{(n-k)}}$. Any thoughts? The first term comes directly from @Ross answer; the second in multiplication is for probability of remaining $n-k$ arrangements that also need to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

For $ k \ll n$ the assumption of independence (while not true) is close.  Any given run is monotonic with probability $\frac 2{k!}$  There are $n-k+1$ runs, so the chance is $(n-k+1)\frac 2{k!}$  As we said $k \ll n$ we should report this as $\frac {2n}{k!}$

Comment: Well, in my case, $k$ is not far smaller than $n$.